# how to make subfigures to have same width and height in latex

Tags: latex, overleaf

Hello I have 7 figures in latex. I want to make all those figures to have the same width and height, Here is what I have tried till now. However as you can see in the result, the figures have not the same height and width. I appreciate if anyone can help me.

```
\begin{figure*}
        \centering
        %\vspace{-2\baselineskip}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        %\baselineskip
        %\includegraphics[height=8cm, width=18cm]{out_1.png}
                \includegraphics[height=8cm\hskip, width=18cm]{out_1.png}
        \end{subfigure}
        %\quad
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[height=8cm\hskip, width=18cm]{out_2.png}
        \end{subfigure}
        \vspace{-11\baselineskip}
        %\quad
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[height=8cm\hskip, width=18cm]{out_3.png}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[height=8cm\hskip, width=18cm]{out_4.png}
        \end{subfigure}
        %\quad
        \vspace{-11\baselineskip}
         \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[height=8cm, width=18cm]{out_5.png}
        \end{subfigure}
        %\quad
         \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[height=8cm, width=18cm]{out_6.png}
        \end{subfigure}
      
        %\vspace{-11\baselineskip}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[height=8cm, width=18cm]{out_7.png}
        \end{subfigure}
        
 \end{figure*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I usually prefer to define the size of figures, subfigures and tables not in absolute terms (*i.e.* with 'cm' or 'pt') but in terms relative to the size of the page geometry. This prevents tables from overshooting the page size and/or overlapping. So, if I want to render three figures on the same line, I define the size of the subfigure one third of the linewidth. In a similar way I set the width of the image to the full width of the 'column' generated by subfigure. Thus, I refactor your code as below:

```tex
\begin{figure*}
    \centering

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}
    %\quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}
    \vspace{1\baselineskip}
    %\quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}
    %\quad
    \vspace{1\baselineskip}
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}
    %\quad
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}
  
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}
        
 \end{figure*}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did what you said but it makes the photos very small and blur and the space between photos arise.

Comment: The differences between the pictures size and/or ratio is high? How much is it quantifiable? 
Maybe [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286737/sub-figures-of-different-sizes-grid-layout) can help you.